# Run Symfony Console Command on Codeception test not persisting changes on db, no errors are thrown

Tags: symfony, doctrine, amazon-sqs, codeception, localstack

I'm having a weird issue with a test that I'm trying to run. I'm consuming a sqs message subscribe to a topic. The message gets processed and the test pass, but there are no changes on the database after the test is done. No exceptions are thrown from doctrine, nothing. It only happens when I use sqs. I created a controller component to test with a different ending point, it works just fine and I can see the changes on the database.

I'm using codeception to set a sqs message. The SqsService class pick up the message and return to me after I call the QUEUE. I have a command class that gets called when I run the queue from my test:

```
runSymfonyConsoleCommand('queue:<command>', ['--queue' => <queue-name>])
```

After that I want to process the message to perform changes on the database by simply doing this, under my service class:

```
$this->repository->remove($entity);
$this->repository->flush();
```

I have an interface injected in my service that serves as an adapter for my entity repository, which extends the entity manager.

Everything works just fine, except that there are no changes expected in the database. I've check all doctrine configurations and they are all setup correctly. I'm using Symfony 4.3.9

Does anybody have a clue of what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it was a simple component of codeception dispatching an event to doctrine. See, when using codeception method:

```
runSymfonyConsoleCommand();
```

You are basically telling doctrine to roll back your database changes, after the sql commands are satisfied by the UnitOfWork. So they are not fully committed.

My work around was using a codeception module called CLI: https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Cli#seeShellOutputMatches

The method:

```
runShellCommand($command);
```

Although, if you are expecting a value back from the command execution, you should simply the built-in PHP method:

```
shell_exec();
```

The codeception method uses exec(); under the hood, so it returns null by default.

I hope this can help the community, thanks.